Postfix being restarted
I have a script that submits form data to my email that works on local host, but not on the server.
main.cf:

# See /usr/share/postfix/main.cf.dist for a commented, more complete version


# Debian specific:  Specifying a file name will cause the first
# line of that file to be used as the name.  The Debian default
# is /etc/mailname.
#myorigin = /etc/mailname

smtpd_banner = $myhostname ESMTP $mail_name (Ubuntu)
biff = no

# appending .domain is the MUA's job.
append_dot_mydomain = no

# Uncomment the next line to generate "delayed mail" warnings
#delay_warning_time = 4h

readme_directory = no

# See http://www.postfix.org/COMPATIBILITY_README.html -- default to 3.6 on
# fresh installs.
compatibility_level = 3.6



# TLS parameters
smtpd_tls_cert_file=/etc/ssl/certs/ssl-cert-snakeoil.pem
smtpd_tls_key_file=/etc/ssl/private/ssl-cert-snakeoil.key

smtp_tls_CApath=/etc/ssl/certs
smtp_tls_session_cache_database = btree:${data_directory}/smtp_scache


smtpd_relay_restrictions = permit_mynetworks permit_sasl_authenticated defer_unauth_destination
myhostname = Laleesh
alias_maps = hash:/etc/aliases
alias_database = hash:/etc/aliases
myorigin = /etc/mailname
mydestination = $myhostname, laleesh.com, Laleesh, localhost.localdomain, localhost
relayhost = [smtp.gmail.com]:587
mynetworks = 127.0.0.0/8 [::ffff:127.0.0.0]/104 [::1]/128 my.ip.address
mailbox_size_limit = 0
recipient_delimiter = +
inet_interfaces = all
inet_protocols = all

smtp_sasl_auth_enable = yes
smtp_sasl_security_options = noanonymous
smtp_sasl_password_maps = hash:/etc/postfix/sasl/sasl_passwd
smtp_tls_security_level = encrypt
smtp_tls_CAfile = /etc/ssl/certs/ca-certificates.crt

[enter image description here][1]
Error log:
root@Laleesh:~# sudo tail -f /var/log/mail.log
2024-05-20T14:36:29.322622+00:00 Laleesh postfix/postfix-script[219384]: starting the Postfix mail system
2024-05-20T14:36:29.341896+00:00 Laleesh postfix/master[219386]: daemon started -- version 3.8.1, configuration /etc/postfix
2024-05-20T18:00:00.629191+00:00 Laleesh postfix/smtpd[222598]: warning: hostname apzg-0727-m-044.stretchoid.com does not resolve to address 192.241.224.14
2024-05-20T18:00:00.629629+00:00 Laleesh postfix/smtpd[222598]: connect from unknown[192.241.224.14]
2024-05-20T18:00:00.630053+00:00 Laleesh postfix/smtpd[222598]: improper command pipelining after CONNECT from unknown[192.241.224.14]: MGLNDD_95.179.164.136_25\n
2024-05-20T18:00:00.798252+00:00 Laleesh postfix/smtpd[222598]: lost connection after UNKNOWN from unknown[192.241.224.14]
2024-05-20T18:00:00.798526+00:00 Laleesh postfix/smtpd[222598]: disconnect from unknown[192.241.224.14] unknown=0/1 commands=0/1
2024-05-20T18:03:20.993726+00:00 Laleesh postfix/anvil[222600]: statistics: max connection rate 1/60s for (smtp:192.241.224.14) at May 20 18:00:00
2024-05-20T18:03:20.995564+00:00 Laleesh postfix/anvil[222600]: statistics: max connection count 1 for (smtp:192.241.224.14) at May 20 18:00:00
2024-05-20T18:03:20.995658+00:00 Laleesh postfix/anvil[222600]: statistics: max cache size 1 at May 20 18:00:00

What is your server config? What does the server log say?

I have provided a link to a screenshot of mail.log and the main.cf configuration is above it.

Why post the contents of a text file as an image? Please include text AS text in the body of the question. Images are not helpful for searching or copying for recreating your situation.

Further, as a convention, the Title is not where the question goes, but should be a helpful bit of initial context. Put a clear question in the post body, including context, configs, things you've tried, outcomes, etc.

Ah, sorry about that, I changed it.
